# Como se hace un for en la rails console para actualizar unos registros?

Tags: base-de-datos, bucle-for, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Al abrir la rails console procedo con la siquiente query

```
notUpDate = Package.where(["state = :elEstado and viality_to < :laFecha", {elEstado: 'published', laFecha: '2022-12-31'}])
```

Luego actualizo la fecha:

```
notUpDate.update_all(viality_to: "2022-12-31".to_date)
```

El problema es que : notUpDate.save no guarda toda la información en la base de datos.

```
6] pry(main)> notUpDate.save
NoMethodError: undefined method `save' for #<Package::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000019533e78>
from /<Proyecto>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:136:in `method_missing'
```

notUpDate.save_all tampoco me funciona:

```
[11] pry(main)> notUpDate.save_all
NoMethodError: undefined method `save_all' for #<Package::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000019533e78>
from <ElProyecto>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:136:in `method_missing'
```

Pero como hago para actualizar todos los valores a la vez?

Estoy pensando en algo como

```
for i en query
   i.update_column :viality_to, "2021-31-21".to_date
   i.save
```

Alguien puede explicarme?

Comment: Pero `update_all` debería haberte actualizado todo, a menos que te esté arrojando un error que no hayas compartido aquí. El método `.save` funciona solo en registros únicos, no en colecciones de datos, que es lo que te retorna `.where`. El `.save_all` no se de donde lo sacaste, pero eso no existe en ActiveRecord.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón el update_all tiene implicito el save :)
Eres un genio... ojalá te pudiera poner como respuesta correcta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ojo: las colecciones Where no necesitan .save o .save_all

El solo hecho de hacer update_all() trae implicito un save